# dialogflow ES NLU training phrases

Tags: dialogflow-es, workflow, nlu

Trying to know how might be the proper way to upload json intents to google dialogflow ES, to better preprocess the information, i came across this doubt.

What is the workflow/pipeline dialogflow NLU? Does it stem and or lemmatize the training phrase ?

Comment: Could you please describe your use case a little more? If you could provide a few specific examples, it would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow automatically expands on your training phrases, so you might not have to use outside tools, however Dialogflow does not seem to use a stemmer per [1](https://chatbotslife.com/nlu-impact-of-using-stemmer-3ab5ad0bf036).